# Unable to start PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

> could not connect to server: No such file or directory    Is the server
>   running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket
>   "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I uninstalled and installed postgresql but nothing works for me.

```
$ sudo service postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 10 database server                                                                                                       
 * Failed to issue method call: Unit postgresql@10-main.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service' for details.

systemctl status postgresql 
Failed to issue method call: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties' on object at path /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/postgresql_2eservice

$ psql -V
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.4 (Ubuntu 10.4-2.pgdg14.04+1)
```

Comment: Make sure you add your server to your `PostgreSQL\9.4\data\pg_hba.conf` file

Comment: What was the issue, did u solve it. I have exacly the same problem

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Does anybody know the answer?

Comment: Is it a new installation or an upgrade? Is this on linux? I also advise to move the question to https://dba.stackexchange.com/ since the question is not related to programming.

Comment: @Salini I answered the question.

Comment: @Salini - if you are encountering this issue in Windows, see [Unable to connect to server: postgresql...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954332/unable-to-connect-to-server-postgresql-on-ubuntu-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux/51955476#51955476)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` is about permission,

did you change the database directory?
if yes so you need to give write and read permission to the postgres

```
sudo chown -R postgres:postgres <directory_path>

or

sudo chmod -R 777 <directory_path>
```

case you cannot use remote access, on `pg_config` edit this line `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` to `listen_addresses = '*'`

and in the `pg_hba.conf` insert this line:

```
host    all  all  0.0.0.0/0  md5
```